# fread cause Signal meaning : Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fread

I want to read a binary file, a struct store in the file, so when I run blow codes, it will cause "segmentation fault".

```
FILE *fp2;

Segment *head = (Segment *)malloc(sizeof(Segment));
if ((fp2 = fopen("/home/zhangchengfei/workspace/test/test/1.1428340272.ram", "rb")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"error to open\n");
   }

head->segleter = (Seglet *)malloc(sizeof(Seglet));
head->segleter->objector = (Object *)malloc(sizeof(Object));

int total = (sizeof(Seglet) + sizeof(Object)) + sizeof(Segment);
if (fread(head, total, 1, fp2) == 0) {
}
fclose(fp2);
```

when I order `Segment *head = (Segment *)malloc(sizeof(Segment));` behind the `fopen()` just like below, it magicly go pass. I test several times, but I didn't get the reason?

Comment: I think you have missed something about locality memory.
As you have have pointer you can't read it in one call. Take a look here: https://techtalk.intersec.com/2014/02/more-about-locality/ Do you have the writing function ?

Comment: You are trying to read 3 separate structs into just one struct.  You either need to use 3 reads to the 3 pointers separately, or you need to malloc one big data structure that can hold all 3 structs at once.

Comment: @Ôrel Writing function is OK，just the code order cause error.

Comment: @Aaron without the writing function, we cannot help you to write the reading function. As JS1 said, you need one big structure or three specific read